# Qt QSqlQuery bindValue works with ? but not with :placeholders

Tags: c++, database, qt, sqlite, qsqlquery

I'm working with SQLite, doing insert into table. Folowwing

```
QSqlQuery testQuery(QString("INSERT INTO test(testcol) VALUES(?)"));
testQuery.bindValue(0, someQStringObg);
testQuery.exec();
```

works, but

```
QSqlQuery testQuery(QString("INSERT INTO test(testcol) VALUES(:val)"));
testQuery.bindValue(":val", someQStringObg);
testQuery.exec();
```

don't. testQuery.lastError().text() returns **No query Unable to fetch row**

Have no clue why things are that way, but really want to find out.

Comment: Which sql type and version are you using? Which Qt version? Which OS, which version? Have you tried explicit .prepate() call to see the return value? Also, it is strange that you mix the "?" and ":" approaches, though that should not matter.

Comment: Try to print out the last query with this: `qDebug () << query->lastQuery()` just to make sure. What does that print out? Also, could you please check if the table exists properly before the insertion of the second case? You could use a command line client for double checking this.

Comment: @LaszloPapp with prepare everything works! Thanks!

Comment: OK, great. Submitted an answer for better readability.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Please use prepare as the [official example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/QSqlQuery.html#approaches-to-binding-values):

```
QSqlQuery testQuery;
testQuery.prepare("INSERT INTO test(testcol) VALUES(:val)");
testQuery.bindValue(":val", someQStringObj);
testQuery.exec();
```

The reason for the error is that the query was executed before binding to the corresponding placeholder. You can see the relevant part of the [constructor documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qsqlquery.html#QSqlQuery-2):

> If query is not an empty string, it will be executed.

Comment: Problem is that using constructor "If query is not an empty string, it will be executed." - So query was being executed before bind...

Comment: "The reason for the error is that the query was executed before binding to the corresponding placeholder" – it doesn't look like the code that doesn't work executes the query before binding to the corresponding placeholder to me... Am I missing something?