# QSqlQuery says parameter count mismatch

Tags: c++, sqlite, qt, qt5, qsqlquery

I am creating a simple SQLite update in my Qt5/C++ program using QSqlQuery.  When I execute the query below I get the error "Parameter count mismatch".  But why?

```
QSqlQuery updateQuery;
updateQuery.prepare("UPDATE mytable SET m=:m WHERE r=:r AND u=:u LIMIT 1");
updateQuery.bindValue(":m", m);
updateQuery.bindValue(":r", r);
updateQuery.bindValue(":u", u);
sqlErrors = !updateQuery.exec();
```

Variables m, r, u are QString's.  I have 3 parameters, and bind all three.  Where's the mismatch?  SO posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20786003/qt-qsqlquery-bindvalue-works-with-but-not-with-placeholders/20786508#20786508) only refer to INSERT commands, but everything else applicable seems right.

Checking lastQuery() confirms the bind substitutions are not happening.  I can also see that the prepare statement is failing (returning false) - yet it looks like valid SQL to me.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the problem is the LIMIT word.  Some SQLite packages are compiled without the SQLITE_ENABLE_UPDATE_DELETE_LIMIT flag.  Which means you cannot add a limit to the update statement.

Seems like an odd feature to turn off by default (as distributed from base repo)...but that's it.